What is the difference between power, throne, and authority in Revelation 13:2?
What is the difference between power, throne, and authority?
Revelation 13:2b NIV

The dragon [that ancient serpent called the devil, or Satan12:9] gave the beast his power and his throne and great authority.

It seems like there is a reason all three are mentioned separately. I've read that the difference between power and authority is the difference between having an ability and having the freedom to use it. Where does the throne fit in?
Satan's throne is mentioned in Revelation 2:13, and spiritual authorities and power structures are mentioned in Ephesians 6:12 and Daniel 10 among other places.

Good question. Up-voted +1. Please see the Tour and the Help, below, as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of question-answer contributions as to how this plays out in practice. Welcome to SE-BH.

Valid question, but I would encourage you not to read too much into every little detail of the word pictures in Revelation. Dottard gives a good answer which shows that the three words all have very similar meanings, and the real focus is a list of words that reinforces the completeness of the subject being discussed (in this case power). John often does this: see eg the lists of worship terms used in Revelation 5.12-13. In general we are to understand these lists as John's way of saying "the whole package" is in view.

What is the difference between power, throne, and authority in  Revelation 13:2b?


Power refers to ability or might.

A throne is a seat or symbol of authority.

Authority is less straightforward. In the OT it is basically interchangeable with "power." All authority is from God (see also Romans 13:1). In the Book of Revelation this is less clear, as this is clearly not godly authority. However it still carries the implication of lawfulness. Thus, in the OP's verse, the beast does not rule in its own right but is given authority from the dragon.


Conclusion: In Revelation 13:2b, power refers to the beast's great might. The throne is the seat or locus of the beast's power, given to it by the dragon. Authority is the orderly basis which enable's the beast to exercise its power.

Good answer that did not deserve a downvote - I have upvoted to balance the ledger.  It appears our old foes are back at work downvoting anything with which they either disagree or do not grasp.

@Dottard ,,,If they were not invisible they would not be foes in my book. I actually appreciate downvotes if they are explained. One can much more easily love one's dialog partner than one's invisible foe.

I fully agree with you.

Great answer and straight to the point.

power is the ability – but just because I have the power doesn’t mean I can use it.
throne is the visibility – if I have throne but no power or not auth, I’m merely a figurehead
authority is the availability – authority means I can use my power. If I have authority but no power, I am no threat.


Chapter 13 continues the revealing of the ways in which the invisible great red dragon, "that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan" works his final deception upon humanity, in order to try to maintain his usurpation of the rightful rule of Christ. To fully grasp the meaning of only one half of one verse in that chapter, one would need to diligently study much more beside. Therefore, I will quote relevant bits from a 614-page book devoted to that.
The verse in question speaks of a symbolic "beast like a leopard", and it is the significance of the power, throne [or, seat] and authority given to it by the dragon that is sought. The dragon is Satan the Devil, as stated in paragraph one, and it is his power, his seat, and his authority that is given.
Chapter 13 reveals two global concepts. That evil adversary uses those powers or authorities that he is in control of to foist his last, and greatest deception over the whole world. Those two concepts are depicted as two beasts, the first arising out of the sea with seven heads, ten horns, upon which are ten crowns. Those heads have the name of blasphemy. This beast has some appearance as of a leopard.
The second beast comes out of the earth, having two horns like a lamb, speaking as a dragon, and "exercising all the power of the first beast before him, whose deadly wound was healed". The second beast is likewise used to deceive humanity.
A crucial difference between the beasts of Rev. ch. 13 and Daniel's visionary beasts is that, in Revelation, they are an amalgamation, not a succession. THE beast of Rev. ch. 13 is a composite. Daniel's series of beasts combine to give form to the beast of Revelation. As this book explains regarding this last-day composite, it has all the features of the Daniel beasts:

"...besides having features of its own, such a composite implies all
those powers envisaged in Daniel, but more. Here is the all-embracing
summation of the entire concept, whilst the successive beasts in Daniel
depicted manifestations of that concept for the succeeding times then
present. But the beast of Revelation 13 answers to time itself...
Now these visions are some six hundred and fifty years apart, yet in
so vast an interval everything that Daniel prophesied had come to
pass... John stands as it were on the edge of the world. He views time
as a whole, and perceives in visionary and symbolic form the
principles which hold good throughout time. Although Daniel saw one
beast rise after the other, John discerns all these beasts as being
various successive manifestations of but one. Here is the true vision
of the history of the world." The Revelation of Jesus Christ, John
Metcalfe, pp. 304-308, extracts,
http://www.johnmetcalfe/publishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

It is necessary to explain this first in order to grasp the awesome extent of the power, throne, and authority of this Revelation beast. The great red dragon is an invisible, evil spirit and no humans can see this. He has to remain invisible to perpetrate his dastardly deception, for if people saw him they would be so terrified and repulsed he would no longer be able to keep pulling their strings from his invisible kingdom of evil. Therefore, he continues to use earthly agencies of his making, Revelation chapter 13 giving the word-picture culmination of the final manifestation of the great red dragon's deceptive scheme.
It is the great red dragon itself that is the power, the throne, and the authority at work in the earthly concepts that it creates, in order to attract human adoration and obedience. People who fall for this concept are being controlled by the very power, throne and authority of this epitome of evil rebellion against God, the great red dragon.
The three adjectives used in Revelation 13 stress just how totally this 'beast' is his creation. We have been warned in the strongest possible terms to believe God's revealed warnings and to resist this global concept from Satan, that will deceive all but the elect. This triad of unholy power, throne, and authority stands in diametric opposition to God's holy power, holy throne, and holy authority. The book of Revelation keeps stressing God's power, throne and authority, whilst simultaneously warning us of the ultimate evil power, throne and authority of the great red dragon. They stand in opposition. That is what we are meant to grasp. My last quote from the book above is:

"The mind of the dragon is to gain the crown rights properly due to
Christ. He will have the crowns. In the graphic imagery of Revelation,
he will gain his end by the power of the beast, that is, the ten
crowned horns. This indicates complete power, as do seven heads
perfect intelligence, not in relation to heaven, but in relation to
the earth.
The beast [out of the sea] - an invisible figurative allusion - will
yet again reign completely with the name of blasphemy; that which is
set up against God: the blasphemy of world dominion forced by the
dragon through this - in fact - idealistic and invisible form, the
'beast'. Mankind as a whole remains - and will remain - wholly
oblivious to what actually takes place in the realm of that which is
invisible, spiritual, and visionary." (Ibid. p. 310)


Up-voted +1, without hesitation. Powerful, precise . . . . .  and prophetic. Very edifying. Thank you.

Note that there is a very close connection between sea-beast of Rev 13 and the dragon of Rev 12 - for example:



No.
Dragon, Rev 12
Sea Beast, Rev 13




1.
Seven heads
Seven heads


2.
10 horns
10 horns


3.
seven diadems
10 diadems


4.
persecutes woman for 1260 days or 3½ years
has authority to act for 42 months


5.
mouth that spews out a river
mouth that speaks blasphemies


6.
has power
Receives dragon's power


7.
has authority
Receives dragon's authority


8.
has a throne
Receives dragon's throne



Now, to the details of the OP's question concerning the three words, power, throne and authority, with meanings taken from BDAG:
δύναμις (dunamis = "power")

potential for functioning in some way, power, might, strength, force,
capability

Specifically, this "power" appears to be used (inter alia) to wage war against the saints and to (attempt) to force people to worship the sea beast as per Rev 13:4, 7, 8.
θρόνος (thronos = "royal throne")
This throne is clearly a royal throne in view of the 10 diadems (= royal crowns) worn by the sea beast.  Thus, the sea beast receives its royal throne = position, from the dragon.  This is confirmed by the almost identical description in Rev 17 where royalty is specifically mentioned.
ἐξουσία (exousia = "authority")


state of control over something, or, 2. potential or resource to command, control or govern, capability, might, power, or, 3. the
right to control or commend something, or, 4. power exercised by
rulers or other in high position by virtue of their office, ruling
power, official power


Thus, the sea beast receives its royal authority to rule and wage war from the dragon.
We can see this clearly at the end of Rev 12 - after the dragon fails to destroy the virtuous woman and her children, the dragon becomes enraged (V17) and then stands on the sand of the shore and calls up two more beasts to help defeat the woman:

the sea beast (Rev 13:1-10) and,
the land beast (Rev 13:11-17)

Both aid the dragon to attempt to defeat the woman and the saints by a combination of waging war, blasphemy and deception.
CONCLUSION
Thus, I would read the phrase, "power, throne and great authority" as a merism of the totality of the sea beast's royal rulership; that is, it owes its entire existence and ability to the dragon.
